# if I send a http request to one of the vertx instance and if it is busy, will it redirect to another vertx instance in a cluster?

Tags: java, https, vert.x

if I send a http request to one of the vertx instance and if it is busy, will it redirect to another vertx instance in a cluster? is there any automatic load balancing inside a vertx instance?

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't.

You should use a real load balancer like nginx or haproxy for this